# PHP regex to find non-espaced letters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace F but not \F.

I've tried the following code, without any luck.

```
preg_replace("/[^\\]F/", "f", $str);
```

Comment: Can the backslash itself be escaped by a backslash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
preg_replace("/(?<!\\\)F/", "f", $str);
```

Comment: +1, nice.  I'm not familiar with that syntax, could you explain the regex?

Comment: Its a negative lookbehind. Check this out and more [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: This is called a zero-width negative look-behind assertion. You can find more about the subject here http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html (not very easy to read but very comprehensive). Basically, it looks for every F that is not preceded by a \   (as mentioned in an another answer, the backslashes need to be there 3 times, once for the string escape and one for the regex escape)

Answer (score 2):

This works.

```
$string = preg_replace('/([^\\\]|^)F/', '$1f', $string);
```

The reason there are three backslashes, is because the first one escapes the second one for the string, and that one escapes the last one for the regex.  Here's a topic on another site about it: http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?t=125752

Update: Thanks to @Damp and @webbiedave

Comment: -1 This does not work as it strips the character preceding the letter (abcF would be replaced by abf)

Comment: @Damp: nice catch.  I'll have to think about this.

Comment: Use a backreference to retain the non-slash character: `preg_replace('/([^\\\\]|^)F/', '$1f', 'Fabc');` I'm also checking for beginning of string. You can also look into negative lookbehinds.