# How to exclude character sequences when matching

Tags: regex

Is there some sort of escape sequence or character in regexes that specify that a specific character should not be found at this place in the pattern?

For instance if I want match a string that has C-style escape sequences but not the specific escape sequence for a literal backslash (Should match `"Hello\tWorld"` but not `"Hello\\World"`) then how would I write the regex so that it matches any '\' but not if followed by ONLY another '\'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As you don't specify your language, here is a perl script that do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.1;

my @l = ("Hello\tWorld", "Hello\\World");

for(@l) {
  say /^.*?\\(?!\\).*$/ ? "$_ -> KO" : "$_ -> OK";
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello   World -> OK
Hello\World -> KO
```

**Explanation:**

```
/       : start regex
^       : begining of the line
  .*?   : any number of any char (not greedy)
  \\    : backslash
  (?!   : negative look ahead
    \\  : backslash
  )     : end of negative look ahead
  .*    : any number of any char
$       : end of line
/
```

Comment: +1 for negative look ahead reference. Now i can google at will.

Answer (score 0):

In most regex syntaxes, you can define an inverse character class using `^`, e.g. `[^a]` matches anything apart from an `a`.

Answer (score 0):

I think a very similar question was just asked a few minutes ago, check it out and see if it helps you: [PHP regex to find non-espaced letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741291/php-regex-to-find-non-espaced-letters/4741394#4741394)

Regex from link: `(?<!\\\)F`

Possible regex for you: `(?<!\\\)[tnr]` which matches \n, \t, or \r